# Using Babylon JS Viewer for local GLTF file

Tags: babylonjs

I am tying to use to Babylon JS Viewer (with Chrome on Windows) to display a local GLTF file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="babylon.viewer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<babylon model="current.gltf" templates.main.params.fill-screen="true"></babylon>
</body>
</html>
```

Opening the web page from a (local) web server (and specifying a full url) works.
But opening the web page from the file system (and only specifying the relative file name does not work (Error: No URL specified in the web console).

I also tried (without success) to supply the model as a data URL.

Do I really need a dummy web server for this?

Answer (score 0):

The babylon viewer supports loading files using the local file system (which, as I understand, is what you are trying to achieve), but you will have to configure the URL correctly using the `file:` schema (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). so the model should look like `file://locationoffile/current.gltf`

Answer (score 0):

you can use Live Server plugin in Visual Studio Code. Browser applications does not allow you to read/load local files; so that, you need to convert your local machine into a local server.